# Python Class: Add a number to each element in a vector using __add__

Tags: python, class, addition

Suppose I have a vector (a_1, a_2, a_3, ... , a_n)

and I want to add a number to each element of my vector using the __add__ in python class.

Such that:

a = vector(7, 4, 2)

print a + 3

will output: (10, 7, 5)

Please help. What would be my code for this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you construct your vector and store a1 to an?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
class vector(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, int):
            raise TypeError("Cannot add {} with {}".format(type(self), type(other)))
        return vector(*(arg + other for arg in self.args))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "vector({})".format(", ".join(map(str, self.args)))


a = vector(7, 4, 2)

print a + 3  # (10, 7, 5)
```

**Output:**

```
vector(10, 7, 5)
```

I assumed your `(10, 7, 4)` was meant to be `(10, 7, 5)`

Comment: I'd recommend implementing `__str__` instead of `__repr__`. Classes that `repr` like a built-in type can be incredibly annoying to detect.

Comment: Ahh yes good point. Let me fix that!

Comment: Hello Guys! Thank you very much for your help. This code work very well. Thank you also for the use of \__repr__, I will be using that too. I am new to python class. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vector():

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __add__(self, other):
        return tuple(map(lambda x:x+other,self.args))

a = Vector(1,2,3,4,5)
print a+3
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I also try this and it also work very well.